# php include not working when switching to SSL

Tags: php, ssl, https, include

I added SSL on my site and and updated the 'http://' to 'https://' in the absolute paths.

I am receiving an error on my relative php include though.

**CODE:**

```
include("connection.php");
```

**Error Message**

> **Warning:** include(connection.php) [function.include]: failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   pathTo/includes/index_header.php
>   on line 57

I am assuming I need to update something to "https" but I don't know where.

Comment: I think this is not related to HTTPS/SSL, because HTTP is not related to PHP

Comment: The error was not occurring a few minutes ago before I put these files on the SSL server, so it needs to have something to do with the SSL

Comment: No, you can check `if(file_exists('connection.php')){echo 'yes'}` and then try to find why?

Comment: ssl can have different virtual server config then the http version. is it possible the that some option like follow symlinks is not enabled on the ssl config?

Comment: the index_header.php files is inside the "includes" folder. From within the index_header.php file, I am trying to include connection.php which sits within the same folder. Since it is in the same folder, I didn't add the folder names in the include, but I just tried adding it, and the error went away. Not sure why that worked.

Comment: Where is the SSL config? In the Cpanel?

Comment: what os/hosting/webserver are you using

Comment: when you installed the cert you would have had to edit it

Comment: Mediatemple gridservice

Comment: im not going to be of any help there

Comment: Maybe your SSL Server runs under a different local user and that user is not allowed to read that file.

Check your include path (should be visible in your Error message). if it's correct, I highly suggest checking user permissions!

Comment: Another possibility (according to your commented solution above) is that you somehow corrupted your includes string. Did it contain proper paths, separated by ":" on linux or ";" on windows? Did it also contain the "." to include files in your local folder?

Answer (score -1):

I think u included `Index_header.php` in `index.php`. ie. It loads the file from the root folder so u needed to add the includes folder: index.php <- index_header.php <- connection.php

you need to do

```
includes("includes/connection.php");
```